# To display sum of qty based on current date and previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i am trying to get sum of qty based on current date and previous date.In my case it is not working it shows null but the values are present in the table.my expected result is

```
Quantity | Date
200      | 20-5-2015
15       | 19-5-2015

Select SUM(RecommentedQuantity) FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
WHERE ID.CreatedOn =GETDATE()
UNION

Select SUM(RecommentedQuantity) FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
WHERE ID.CreatedOn =       dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
```

Comment: what is the datatype of column `CreatedOn`? `DATE / VARCHAR / DATETIME`? Also Post your input data as well in your question

Comment: @ughai it is datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `NULL` is because in your WHERE clause `ID.CreatedOn =GETDATE()` both `GETDATE()` and `CreatedOn` have a time component which will not match.

You can rewrite your query like this.

```
Select SUM(RecommentedQuantity) FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
WHERE ID.CreatedOn >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) AND ID.CreatedOn < CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,1,GETDATE()))
UNION

Select SUM(RecommentedQuantity) FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
    WHERE ID.CreatedOn >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())) AND ID.CreatedOn < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Or a single query as

```
Select CONVERT(DATE,ID.CreatedOn),SUM(RecommentedQuantity)
FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
WHERE ID.CreatedOn >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())) AND ID.CreatedOn < CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,1,GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,ID.CreatedOn)
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005, then you can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ID.CreatedOn,112)` instead of `CONVERT(DATE,ID.CreatedOn)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
Select SUM(RecommentedQuantity) FROM IndentDetails ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Indent I On I.IndentID=ID.IndentID
WHERE ID.CreatedOn between convert(date,getdate()) and convert(date,getdate()-1)
```

Comment: Good answer! Maybe i would use 
DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) 
or 
DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE()) instead of GETDATE()-1